# Переменные окружения в QNX 6.5.0

Tags: unix, qnx

С помощью команды export могу посмотреть наличие переменных окружения, а вот где они находятся и какое у них значение не знаю.

Смотрел каталог /etc/profile, /root/.profile там только стандартные, export показывает больше.

Как посмотреть значение остальных?

Я знаю об утилитах : set,env,export. Но у меня такой вопрос - где они хранятся, я бы хотел их перенести с одного компьютера на другой, один в один.

Answer (score 2):

> Как посмотреть значение остальных?

Узнать значения переменных среды (enviroment variables) можно с помощью команд:

- [`env`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/utilities/e/env.html), покажет список переменных, предназначенных только для "экспорта";
- [`set`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-unix/), покажет список всех переменных среды.

*Дополнено вследствие дополнения вопроса автором:*

> ... где они хранятся? я бы хотел их перенести с одного компьютера на другой, один в один.

В таком виде, как вам представляется (обычный текстовый файл, который можно скопировать), переменные не хранятся.

Вам нужно определиться, какие именно переменные вам нужно перенести. Затем в новой системе прописать их инициализацию. Это можно сделать

- глобально, в файле `/etc/profile` или в соотв. скрипте в директории `/etc/profile.d`;
- для конкретного пользователя в `$HOME/.profile` или в `$HOME/.kshrc`.

Подробней об этом вы можете узнать в документации [Configuring Your Environment](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/user_guide/environment.html).